# CollectionFS and Meteor: how to join uploaded files with existing collection

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have tickets collection created by autoform. After one ticket creation, I need to upload a files as attachment releated to this one. All works fine when files is not in relationship to anyone. But when I try to add a field in the collection with the current object ID, nothing appears.
My code:

Collection:

```
tickets = new Mongo.Collection("tickets");
var Schemas = {};
Schemas.tickets = new SimpleSchema({

    title: {
      type: String,
      label: "Titolo"
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      label: "Descrizione"
    },
    deadline: {
      type: Date,
      label: "Deadline prevista"
    },
    user: {
      type: String,
      autoValue:function(){ return this.userId; }
    },
    status: {
      type: String,
      autoValue: function(){ return "open"; }
    }

});

tickets.attachSchema(Schemas.tickets);

SimpleSchema.messages({
  "required title": "Il [label] è richiesto",
  "required description": "La [label] è richiesta",
  "required deadline": "La [label] è richiesta"
});
//
Files = new FS.Collection("Files", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("Files", {path: "~/uploads"})]
});
```

and template:

```
Template.dashboard.events({
  'click #fileUpload' : function(event, template) {
    var file = template.find('.myFileInput').files[0];
    var ticket = this._id;
      Files.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log(ticket);
          tickets.update({_id: ticket}, {$push: {files: ticket}});
        }
      });
  }
});
```

if you have any other method to suggest me please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#storing-fsfile-references-in-your-objects

Or you can make 'metadata' field for your files collection and then connect it with your ticket collection so:

```
Template.dashboard.events({
  'click #fileUpload' : function(event, template) {
    var file = template.find('.myFileInput').files[0];
    var ticket = this._id;
    var newFile = new FS.File(file);
    newFile.metadata = {
        ticketId: ticket //ticket id - so you know that this file is from particular ticket, you can then find it by Files.find({'metadata.ticketId': ticket});
    };
      Files.insert(newFile, function (err, fileObj) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: Your solution works fine for me, thx! Now I have another issue: in the template I have this code inside {{#each tickets}}:
`{{#each files}}
                              <div class="file">
                                  <strong>{{this.name}}</strong> <a href="{{this.url download=true}}" class="btn btn-primary">Download</a>
                              </div>
                          {{/each}}`
but download button don't work now... :-(